# Using future dates with Mongo TTL

Tags: mongodb

we are currently experimenting with Mongo's new TTL feature and would like records to expire based on a date that is in the "future" as of the creation time of the record. This is so different records can have different periods of validity.

For example, something like this:

```
db.createCollection("sushi")
db.sushi.ensureIndex({"best_before": 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 1})
db.sushi.insert({name: "ngiri", best_before: new Date('2012/10/02')})
```

But in our initial tests documents do not get removed from the collection if the indexed date field is in the future at the time of the creation of the record.
Is there any reason why this shouldn't work?

Thanks

Comment: Seemed to work fine when I tried that.  Are you sure it's not working?

Comment: can you provide output for `db.sushi.getIndexes()` please?

Comment: also, db.sushi.find() may be helpful - is it possible there are time zone issues here?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was daylight saving that go me here. Lesson learnt.